# Ignore certificate while executing the API Tests

Tags: java, api, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am getting SSL exception errors when i execute the API Tests, I want to ignore them in the NON prod environment while I m executing. Please let me know how I can do that..

I m using Rest Assured with Cucumber for my API Tests

Answer (score 1):

The following line can fix your issue: `RestAssuredConfig.newConfig().sslConfig((new SSLConfig()).relaxedHTTPSValidation().allowAllHostnames()`

Comment: I m still getting the error 
`avax.net.ssl.SSLException: Certificate for <host> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [host2]
 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:177)
 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:62)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste some code samples? It might be because of missing http or wrong port.

Comment: Pasted the code below.

 `this.setRequest(RestAssured.given().auth().preemptive()
    .basic(ConfigHelper.getString(user + ".username"), ConfigHelper.getString(user + ".password"))
    .header("Content-type", "multipart/form-data")
    .multiPart("file", new File("src/test/resources/test-data/" + fileName), "application/json")
    .config(RestAssuredConfig.newConfig()
      .sslConfig((new SSLConfig()).relaxedHTTPSValidation().allowAllHostnames())));`

Comment: Do you set the port somewhere?

Comment: in the Url itself, not anywhere else

Comment: Try setting the port by using RestAssured.port = port instead of adding it to the URL directly